# How to connect and disconnect bluetooth headphones with python?

Tags: python, automation, bluetooth, headphones

I tried to search good way to automatically connect bluetooth headphones and/or disconnect them with python 3 but couldn't find any good solutions. Is there any good libraries or tutorials how I could accomplish this task?

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: Windows and Mac on different computers. Ideal solution would work with both of them but help with either one is great